# Ansible parse JSON output

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to parse the Ansible output the print a value

```
- name: Creating a new instance
  os_server:
  state: present
  auth:
  auth_url: "{{ auth_url }}"
  username: "{{ username }}"
  password: "{{ password }}"
  project_name: "{{ project_name }}"
name: "{{ item.hostname }}"
image: "{{ item.image }}"
nics: "{{ nics }}"
with_items: "{{ servers }}"
register: "os"
```

Output:

```
"server": {
    "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", 
    "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "zoneA", 
    "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, 
    "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, 
    "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", 
    "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2018-04-01T18:53:16.000000", 
    "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, 
    "accessIPv4": "10.190.230.23", 
    "accessIPv6": "", 
    "addresses": {
        "provider_corenet_bif_757": [
            {
                "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:1:3:3:5e:6a", 
                "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed", 
                "addr": "10.19.23.23", 
                "version": 4
            }
        ], 
        "provider_nmnet_bif_912": [
            {
                "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:1:3:39:b:57", 
                "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed", 
                "addr": "10.25.13.64", 
                "version": 4
            }
        ]

      server.addresses.provider_nmnet_bif_912.addr

    },
```

I want to parse addr "10.25.13.64".

I tried {{ item.server.addresses.provider_nmnet_bif_912.addr }} and {{os.server.addresses.provider_nmnet_bif_912.addr}} both didnot work.

Need Help!!!

Comment: Run `debug: var=os` and see what's inside. Also read what `{ }` and `[ ]` mean in JSON.

Comment: I am unable to parse, I tried several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

> "{{ item.server.addresses.provider_nmnet_bif_912[0].addr }}"

Comment: hey can you please print the full solution? I am loosing in syntax.

like how exactly your task looks?